# This connector is disabled. Please check the "editor/filemanager/connectors/php/config.php" file

Tags: php, asp.net, c#-3.0

while uploading image in fckeditor.i am  getting following error.

This connector is disabled. Please check the "editor/filemanager/connectors/php/config.php" file

please give solution asap.

Answer (score 0):

First check is the full permission to the image folder is given if itis ok 
try this in

"editor/filemanager/connectors/aspx/config.aspx"

`private bool CheckAuthentication()`

```
{
    // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
    // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
    // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
    //
    //        return ( Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] != null && (bool)Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] == true );
    //
    // ... where Session[ "IsAuthorized" ] is set to "true" as soon as the
    // user logs in your system.
    MembershipUser m = Membership.GetUser();
    if (m != null)
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    //return false;
}
```